# Find the element with the most "neighbors" in a sequence

Tags: algorithm

Assume that we have a sequence S with n elements `<x1,x2,...,xn>`. A pair of elements `xi,xj` are considered neighbors if `|xi-xj|<d`, with `d` a given distance between two neighbors. So how can find out the element that has most neighbors in the sequence?

(A simple way is sorting the sequence and then calculating number of each element but it's time complexity is quite large):

```
O(nlogn)
```

May you please help me find a better way to reduce time complexity?

Comment: sounds like homework. what have you figured out so far?

Comment: nlogn is actually pretty darn good... What's the requirement, and what could you hope for better than nlogn?

Comment: As I want to find out the most dense area in a range of value on a large dataset, so if it can be reduced more?

Comment: @Bao An: what kind of `N` are we talking about here? And are the numbers integers bounded by `k`? How is `d` compared to `N` and `k`?

Comment: @Polygenelubicants: Thanks for your help. I want use this for real data, and have no bound of number of values, so it may difficult to form the appear[] array. Let me consider more.......

Comment: Suppose the sequence is [3,2,1,4,5].  Then 2,3,4 each have two neighbors that are d=1 away.  What should the result be?

Answer (score 3):

`O(N log N)` isn't "quite large"; `log` is a very slow growing function!

This can not be done in time less than `O(N)` since you have to read the whole input. You *can* do it in `O(N)` if you know the range of the numbers, in which case you can use any of `O(N)` sorting methods (e.g. counting sort/bucket sort, radix sort).

---

Here's a `O(dN)`-time, `O(N + k)`-space solution based on counting sort, implemented in Java.

```
static int mostNeighbors(int k, int d, int... nums) {
    boolean[] appears = new boolean[k];
    int[] neighborCount = new int[k];
    int most = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
        appears[num] = true;
        for (int i = num - d + 1; i < num + d; i++) {
            if (i < 0 || i >= k) continue;
            if (++neighborCount[i] > neighborCount[most] && appears[i]) {
                most = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return most;
}

// ...
System.out.println(mostNeighbors(10, 2, 0,0,0,2,2,2)); // prints 0
System.out.println(mostNeighbors(10, 2, 0,0,0,2,2,2,1)); // prints 1
System.out.println(mostNeighbors(10, 2, 1,2,3,4,5,3)); // prints 2
```

Basically for each `num`, it increments `neighborCount[num-d+1..num+d-1]` that are in range of `0..k-1`. Not all of the numbers in this range actually appears in the array, so `appears` is used to keep track of that. `most` is used to keep track of the best found so far.

Comment: As I want to find out the most dense area in a range of value on a large dataset, so if it can be reduced more?